# Substituir foreach php por each jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Estou usando jQuery para printar retornos de um Web Service JSON, o script funciona normalmente, mas o carregamento da página esta muito lento, eu estou usando tags do PHP dentro do meu script jQuery, gostaria de usar somente o jQuery e vi que a função each serve para percorrer Arrays, mas não tenho certeza em como aplica-la, e também não tenho certeza se a forma que escrevi o código está correta, poderiam me dar dicas de como proceder?

**agenda.php**

```
<?php

$dt = date('Y') . '';
$dm = date('m') . '';

$api_campeonatos = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/campeonatos?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL&ano=2018&status=A';
$campeonatos = wp_remote_get( $api_campeonatos );
$campeonato = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $campeonatos ), true );

$api_resultados = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/resultados?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL&inicio=2018-'. $dm .'-01&fim='. $dt .'-12-31';
$resultados = wp_remote_get( $api_resultados );
$resultado = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $resultados), true);

$api_equipes = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/equipes?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL';
$equipes = wp_remote_get( $api_equipes );
$equipe = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $equipes ), true );

$api_locais = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/locais?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL';
$locais = wp_remote_get( $api_locais );
$local = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $locais ), true );

$api_categorias = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/categorias?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL';
$categorias = wp_remote_get( $api_categorias );
$categoria = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $categorias ), true );

$api_modalidades = 'https://sportsmanager.com.br/api/modalidades?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SXLSO8342HSDE78623GVS7234GNMSKL';
$modalidades = wp_remote_get( $api_modalidades );
$modalidade = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $modalidades ), true );

$retorno_resultados = array();

if(!is_array($equipe) && !is_array($local) && !is_array($categoria) && !is_array($modalidade)){

    print_r('Não encontrado');

}else{

$col =  array_column($equipe, 'codigo');

$loc =  array_column($local, 'codigo');

$cat =  array_column($categoria, 'codigo');

$mod =  array_column($modalidade, 'codigo');

    foreach($campeonato as $camp){

            if(empty($camp) && !is_array($camp)){

            }else{

                foreach($resultado as $result){

                    if(empty($result) && !is_array($result)){

                }else{

                    if(isset($camp['categoria']) && isset($camp['modalidade']) && isset($result['mandante']) && isset($result['visitante']) && isset($result['local']) && isset($result['data'])) {

                        $categorizacao = '';
                        $key1 = array_search($camp['categoria'], $cat); 

                        if($key1){
                            $categorizacao = $categoria[$key1]['nome'];
                        }

                        $modalidadez = '';
                        $key2 = array_search($camp['modalidade'], $mod);

                        if($key2){
                            $modalidadez = $modalidade[$key2]['nome'];
                        }

                        $mandante = '';
                        $key3 = array_search($result['mandante'], $col);

                        if($key3){
                            $mandante = $equipe[$key3]['nome'];
                        }

                        $visitante = '';
                        $key4 = array_search($result['visitante'], $col);

                        if($key4){
                            $visitante = $equipe[$key4]['nome'];
                        }

                        $localizacao = '';
                        $key5 = array_search($result['local'], $loc);

                        if($key5){
                            $localizacao = $local[$key5]['nome'];
                        }

                        $data = $result['data'];
                        $data = date('d/m/Y', strtotime($data));

                        $i = 0;

                        if(isset($camp['codigo']) && isset($result['campeonato']) && $camp['codigo'] == $result['campeonato']){
                            $retorno_resultados[++$i][] = array(
                                'mandante' => $result['mandante'], 
                                'visitante' => $result['visitante'],
                                'nm_mandante' => $mandante,
                                'nm_visitante' => $visitante,
                                'nm_cat' => $categorizacao,
                                'nm_mod' => $modalidadez,
                                'nm_local' => $localizacao,
                                'id' => $camp['codigo'],
                                'modalidade' => $camp['modalidade'],
                                'categoria' => $camp['categoria'],
                                'data' => $result['data'],
                                'data_certa' => $data,
                                'placar1n' => $result['placar1n'],
                                'placar2n' => $result['placar2n'],
                                'placar1p' => $result['placar1p'],
                                'placar2p' => $result['placar2p'],
                                'placar1s' => $result['placar1s'],
                                'placar2s' => $result['placar2s'],
                                'jogo' => $result['jogo'],
                                'horario' => $result['horario'],
                                'jogo' => $result['codigo'],
                            );
                        };
                    };
                };
            };
        };
    };
};

?>
```

**jQuery**

```
<script>

 $(function() {

    <?php foreach($retorno_resultados as $val){ ?>

    var html3 = '';
    var id='';

    <?php foreach($val as $res){ ?>


    html3 += '<tr><td><?php echo $res['data_certa'];?>&nbsp às &nbsp<?php echo $res['horario'];?></td><td><?php echo $res['nm_local'];?></td><td><?php echo $res['nm_mandante'];?></td><td><?php echo $res['nm_visitante'];?></td><td><?php echo $res['nm_mod']?>&nbsp<?php echo $res['nm_cat']?></td></tr>';

    id = <?php echo $res['id'] ?>;

    <?php } ?>
    $('#equipesTbody').html(html3);

    <?php } ?>

});

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
    <div class="agenda-modalidades">

    <?php include_once 'agenda.php'; ?>

        <table id="agendatabelas" class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Data</th>
                    <th>Local</th>
                    <th>Mandante</th>
                    <th>Visitante</th>
                    <th>Mod / Cat</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody id="equipesTbody">

            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Vc só pode fazer isso usando AJAX par jogar um PHP e recuperar os valores no JS.

Comment: eu uso php pra filtrar os dados em outra função, eu gostaria de otimizar o jquery, é difícil?

Comment: Porque estás a usar jQuery se já tens os registos no PHP? Não tens acesso ao elemento `#equipesTbody` a partir do PHP?

Comment: é minha primeira vez consumindo Web Service, não encontrei nada que me ajuda-se a faze-lo em php, então recorri ao jquery, sou iniciante ainda.

Comment: Consegues mostrar o HTML que gera a tabela que vai mostrar as equipas? Onde tens o elemento `#equipesTbody`. Consegues editar esse código e mudar essa tabela, se sim, eu sugeria que usasses o que já tens no PHP para mostrar lá os resultados directo, em vez de os pores na página para o jQuery "apanhar" e depois actualizar a tabela?

Comment: adicionei as informações como pediu, estou fazendo da seguinte forma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### PHP e include_once

No PHP quando incluis outros ficheiros num ficheiro (`include`, `include_once`), ao processar esse ficheiro, o PHP, vai gerir esse código como se fosse todo um só ficheiro (o tal que chama o `include`), logo, variaveis definidas dentro de um ficheiro que está num include, estão acessíveis no *pai*.

### Mostrando a informação

Com a informação que postaste, e sem poder testar, o que eu faria era no **agenda.php** remover a tag `<script>` onde tens o jQuery, tudo o que está dentro dela, apagava para cima até a tag que fecha o PHP `?>`, removia a tag inclusive, mas parava ai, sem fechar o PHP.

É [boa prática quando o ficheiro só tem PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

> Se um arquivo for código PHP puro, é preferível omitir a tag de fechamento no final do arquivo. Prevenindo a existência de espaços ou linhas em branco após a tag, que podem causar efeitos indesejáveis, por que o PHP iniciará o buffer de saída quando não existir intenção do programador de enviar alguma saída neste ponto do script.

De seguida, no HTML, na tabela onde queres listar os resultados, actualizava a parte do `equipesTbody` para ser assim

```
<tbody id="equipesTbody">
<?php foreach($retorno_resultados as $val): ?>
    <?php foreach($val as $res): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $res['data_certa'];?>&nbsp; às &nbsp;<?php echo $res['horario'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $res['nm_local'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $res['nm_mandante'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $res['nm_visitante'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $res['nm_mod']?>&nbsp;<?php echo $res['nm_cat']?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

### Performance

Na verdade, o teu problema de performance parece estar no número de chamadas a APIs externas que fazes. Há várias formas de melhorar este aspecto, mas acho que para já, conseguires por a funcionar é o mais importante, melhorar performance podes colocar outra pergunta depois.

Comment: funcionou!! muito obrigado. Por favor, poderia me dizer também, referente a performance para que eu possa pesquisa-la?

Comment: Tens algumas formas de fazer isso. O mais simples seria ver se realmente precisas de chamar todas essas APIs para mostrar a informação que precisas. Outra opção é usar directamente a biblioteca `Requests` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/requests/) e o método `request_multiple` (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/requests/request_multiple/) para disparar todos os pedidos ao mesmo tempo (async). Já está incluída no wordpress, dai sugerir essa. Tens aqui (em inglês) uma pequena explicacao https://torquemag.io/2017/09/guide-async-http-requests-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

Tente utilizar algo como:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get( "http://meusite.com/", function(data) {
         var obj = JSON.parse(data);

        obj.forEach(function(o, index){
            console.log(o);
        });
    });
});
```

Tenta isto e coloca o resultado do console.log ai

Comment: no local da url eu coloco o a url de retorno em json ou a url do site?

Comment: Se você busca esse JSON de alguma URL, coloca a URL no lugar de http://meusite.com/

Comment: SE já tem esse JSON no javascript, elimine a segunda e a penúltima linha e coloque seu JSON no lugar de JSON.parse(data); da terceira linha.

Comment: var obj = SEU JSON AQUI;

obj.forEach(function(o, index){
      console.log(o);
     //vai percorrer seu json item a item e os valores estarão na variavel o
});